# Как вектор c++ заполнить объектами разных классов?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование, виртуальная-функция

Я хочу запонить вектор объектами разных классов, а потом посчитать их точки в пространстве и первую производную. У меня всего три объекта: окружность, эллипс и спираль, у классов есть родитель окружность. Не понимаю, почему все время вызываются методы только родительского класса, а не наследуемых от него. Всегда вызывается метод Calculate класса Circle. В чем моя ошибка?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

#define PI 3.14159265
using namespace std;

class Circle {
protected:
    double r, t, derivative, x, y, z = 0;
    vector <double> Info;

    void Calculate() {
        this->x = r * cos(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->y = r * sin(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->derivative = -cos(t * PI / 180.0) / sin(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->Info = { x, y, z, derivative };
    }

public:
    Circle(){
    }
    Circle(double r) {
        this->r = r;
    }
    vector <double> GetInfo() {
        this->Calculate();
        return Info;
    }

    double GetRadius() {
        return r;
    }
    void SetT(double t) {
        this->t = t;
    }
};

class Ellips: public Circle {
protected:
    double r1, r2, x, y, derivative;
    vector <double> radiuses;

    void Calculate() {
        this->x = r1 * cos(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->y = r2 * sin(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->derivative = -r2 * cos(t * PI / 180.0) / r1 * sin(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->Info = { x, y, z, derivative };
    }
public:
    Ellips(double r1, double r2) {
        this->r1 = r1;
        this->r2 = r2;
        radiuses = { r1,r2 };
    }

    vector <double> GetRaduises() {
        return radiuses;
    }
};

class Helix : public Circle {
protected:
    double z, step;

    void Calculate() {
        this->x = r * cos(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->y = r * sin(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->z = step * (t * PI / 180.0);
        this->derivative = -step * sin(t * PI / 180.0) / cos(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->Info = { x, y, z, derivative };
    }
public:
    Helix(double r, double step) {
        this->r = r;
        this->step = step;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int countOfElements = 3 + rand() % 15;
    vector <Circle> randomList;
    int number;
    for (int i = 0; i < countOfElements; i++) {
        number = 1 + rand() % 3;
        switch (number) {
        case 1: {;
            randomList.push_back(Circle(rand() % 15));
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            randomList.push_back(Ellips(rand() % 15, rand() % 15));
            break;
        }
        case 3:
            randomList.push_back(Helix(rand() % 15, rand() % 360));
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfElements; i++) {
        randomList[i].SetT(45);
        vector <double> tempInfo = randomList[i].GetInfo();
        for (double j : tempInfo) {
            cout << j << "| \t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/5.11.php

Comment: Раз уж вы хотите полиморфизма, то нужные функции должны быть виртуальными, а хранить в векторе надо указатели на объекты. При помещении в вектор объектов класса они "срезаются" до родительского, так что в векторе есть только `Circle`. Но даже если бы срезки не было, то без виртуальных функций всегда бы вызывались функции-члены `Circle`.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @Harry
@Стас
Помогите еще пожалуйста)Теперь я не могу нормально разыменовать элменеты вектора, идей, что сделать не понимаю

`vector <Circle*> randomList;`
тут цикл

`switch (number) {
 case 1: {
  randomList[i] = &Circle(rand() % 15);
  break;
 }
 case 2: {
  randomList[i] = &Ellips(rand() % 15, rand() % 15);
  break;
 }
 case 3:
  randomList[i] = &Helix(rand() % 15, rand() % 360);
  break;
 }

for (int i = 0; i < countOfElements; i++) {
 randomList[i].SetT(45);
 vector <double> tempInfo = randomList[i].GetInfo(); - ошибка, он должен иметь тип класса,а  не указателя
}`

Comment: *"Я хочу запонить вектор объектами разных классов"* - это невозможно.

Comment: @user7860670
Возможно, если есть один родительский, а остальные наследники

Comment: @AlenaKharicheva в этом случае вектор содержит указатели (реже ссылки), а не сами объекты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вобщем, чтоб с минимальными переделками вашего кода — то вот так. Хотя я бы переделал побольше :), но для понимания должно хватить...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

#define PI 3.14159265
using namespace std;

class Circle {
protected:
    double r, t, derivative, x, y, z = 0;
    vector <double> Info;

    virtual void Calculate() {
        this->x = r * cos(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->y = r * sin(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->derivative = -cos(t * PI / 180.0) / sin(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->Info = { x, y, z, derivative };
    }
    virtual ~Circle() {}

public:
    Circle(){
    }
    Circle(double r) {
        this->r = r;
    }
    vector <double> GetInfo() {
        this->Calculate();
        return Info;
    }

    double GetRadius() {
        return r;
    }
    void SetT(double t) {
        this->t = t;
    }
};

class Ellips: public Circle {
protected:
    double r1, r2, x, y, derivative;
    vector <double> radiuses;

    virtual void Calculate() {
        this->x = r1 * cos(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->y = r2 * sin(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->derivative = -r2 * cos(t * PI / 180.0) / r1 * sin(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->Info = { x, y, z, derivative };
    }
public:
    Ellips(double r1, double r2) {
        this->r1 = r1;
        this->r2 = r2;
        radiuses = { r1,r2 };
    }

    vector <double> GetRaduises() {
        return radiuses;
    }
    virtual ~Ellips() {}
};

class Helix : public Circle {
protected:
    double z, step;

    virtual void Calculate() {
        this->x = r * cos(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->y = r * sin(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->z = step * (t * PI / 180.0);
        this->derivative = -step * sin(t * PI / 180.0) / cos(t * PI / 180.0);
        this->Info = { x, y, z, derivative };
    }
public:
    Helix(double r, double step) {
        this->r = r;
        this->step = step;
    }
    virtual ~Helix() {}
};

int main()
{
    int countOfElements = 3 + rand() % 15;
    vector <Circle*> randomList;
    int number;
    for (int i = 0; i < countOfElements; i++) {
        number = 1 + rand() % 3;
        switch (number) {
        case 1: {;
            randomList.push_back(new Circle(rand() % 15));
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            randomList.push_back(new Ellips(rand() % 15, rand() % 15));
            break;
        }
        case 3:
            randomList.push_back(new Helix(rand() % 15, rand() % 360));
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfElements; i++)
    {
        randomList[i]->SetT(45);
        vector <double> tempInfo = randomList[i]->GetInfo();
        for (double j : tempInfo) {
            cout << j << "| \t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for(auto c: randomList) delete c;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В родителе надо за`=default`ить копирующие и перемещающие констурктор и присваивание. Иначе, из-за наличия кастомного деструктора, остаются только копирующие операции, и попытка переместить класс втихую приводит к копированию. Поэтому же в потомках лучше никакой деструктор не писать (виртуальный сам унаследуется), чтобы не надо было писать ту же портянку с `=default`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat
спасибо!)